Add arbitrary number of years (or months or days) to date time cell value in libreoffice/openoffice calc
I have a column of cells containing a date/time (eg: "05/15/24 10:28 PM") and I want to take those values and add 5 years (eg:  "05/15/29 10:28 PM") to populate another column. So far, I have only found that I can do =DATE(YEAR(A2)+5,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)) but it truncates the time (results in:  "05/15/29 12:00 AM"). I looked at edate() and that doesn't seem to work either (same problem).
So, how do I add 5 years to the date time value and keep the time?
I've scoured the manuals and searched online, to no avail. I even tried seeing if I could find how to do this in excel, but no luck there either.

As it often happens, moments after I post the question, I test an idea, and it solves the problem. For anyone else out there trying to do the same thing, here's what solved it for me:
=EDATE(A2,5*12)+TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2))

openoffice version:
=EDATE(A2;5*12)+TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);SECOND(A2))

